# Logic with dictionary and list

Tags: python

I executed this snippet:

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [ 88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

students=[lloyd, alice, tyler]

for i in students:
    for f in i:
        print i[f]
```

I don't understand why output is the next:

```
[88.0, 40.0, 94.0]
[75.0, 90.0]
Lloyd
[90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0]
[82.0, 83.0, 91.0]
[89.0, 97.0]
Alice
[100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0]
[0.0, 75.0, 78.0]
[100.0, 100.0]
Tyler
[0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0]
```

Why it happens so? Where I can find docs for that? Could someone give me short explanation for logic of output?

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered.

Comment: dictionaries are unordered. what do you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regular dictionaries are not ordered.

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value
> pairs
>
> [Source](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

If you really need an ordered dictionary, look into [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects).

Answer (score 6):

Dictionary keys don't have a defined ordering. `{'a':1,'b':2}` and `{'b':2,'a':1}` are considered equal, and they print out the same way:

```
>>> {'a':1, 'b':2}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> {'b':2, 'a':1}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Note, also, from your own experience, that you can't assume they'll come out in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily fix this with a changed loop:

```
for student in students:
    for key in ["name", "homework", "quizzes", "tests"]:
        print student[key]
```

Namedtuples might be a better match here:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Student = namedtuple('Student', ["name", "homework", "quizzes", "tests"])

students = [
    Student(name="Lloyd",
            homework=[90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
            quizzes=[ 88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
            tests=[75.0, 90.0])
    Student(name="Alice",
            homework=[100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
            quizzes=[82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
            tests=[89.0, 97.0])
    Student(name="Tyler",
            homework=[0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
            quizzes=[0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
            tests=[100.0, 100.0])
]
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to consider `get_vals = operator.itemgetter('name', 'homework', 'quizzes', 'tests')` then `for student in studuents: print get_vals(student)`